# What does error 3004 mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

While attempting to play the D3 beta, I'm getting error 3004 when attempting to start a game.  This is happening after choosing my character, and clicking resume game.
[image: Error message]

This error message is very succinct, but I can't help but want more information.  Is this an error from my end, or does it originate from Blizzard's servers?  More details are needed so I know what action to take.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Servers are unavailable** (most likely due to overload). (It's not you, it's them.) 3004 shows at character selection, 37 shows at login—same conditions.

Blizzard's official response: keep trying.

Comment: It's nice to know that i can't play my *single player game* because i can't log into some server.... ugh.

Comment: Page not found, link broken

Comment: dead links removed

Answer (score 25):

### Error Codes & Troubleshooting

- **Error 12** - This is an error we're still investigating but you can
  workaround it by simply changing your Battle.net account password to
  force your account information to refresh. Once changed you can
  change it back.
- **Error 33** and **34200** - The service is undergoing maintenance, please
  try again later.
- **Error 37** - The server is full. This is likely due to us lower the
  concurrency cap to address an issue or error. The only solution is to
  keep trying to log in.
- **Error 24000** - Once logged in you may run into this error when
  attempting to start a game. We're aware and are working to resolve it
  as quickly as possible.
- **Error 3003** or **Error 75** - Click Options, under Account change your
  region to The Americas. The open beta is only being held on US
  hardware.
- **Error 3004**, **3006**, **3007**, or **300008** - These are all related to timeouts
  or creation errors for characters or games. These are server-side
  issues, and need to be resolved on the game side. There are no
  workarounds for these errors except to try again.
- **Error 315300** - If you're sure you're typing your correct account
  information, check to ensure no additional spaces were added before
  or after your email address. If you're still running into this issue
  there may be an error in your foreign language appdata files. Some
  players have [found a workaround](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4427665744?page=3#44) but please be aware the steps they
  provide are not something we can currently support.
- **Gray login button** - You need to use your Battle.net email address as
  your account name. Your BattleTag is a nickname, not your account
  name.
- No Licence Attached - Please add a Battletag to your account from
  [here](https://us.battle.net/login/en/?ref=https://us.battle.net/account/management/battletag-create.html&app=bam&cr=true)
- Updating Setup Files - If you're stuck on "Updating Setup Files" try
  [these troubleshooting steps](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/4511762211).
- Crashes - For any crashes please visit the [Technical Support](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/3374140/) forum or
  [Mac Technical Support](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/3462866/)

### Tips

- Please remember to get and use the beta client, not the pre-download
  retail client
- It's best to let the launcher finish the entire download before you
  login to avoid potential issues
- During the stress test, lag and connection issues may occur
- Please do **not** change languages in-game. This functionality is not
  working correctly yet and will cause the client to crash
- This is an open stress test – not a demo and certainly not a finished
  product. You may experience a number of issues and errors, but this
  is exactly what helps us to prepare for the smoothest launch possible
  on May 15

Source: [The Blue from Battle.net forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4511822204#1)

Comment: Can you summarize the contents of that link? There's no guarantee it won't change or disappear, in which case your answer would be useless.

Answer (score 3):

Try "spam-clicking" the start button. As in, clicking start, then hitting the enter key immediately after the error pops up; repeat. I can't say it is what the folks at Blizzard would want/recommend (can't find an official response), but it is what others seem to be doing with some degree of success. Possibly because the servers may able to support more players, but the login process maybe demands a bit more resources all at once, when compared to simply keeping you playing once already in-game?

It worked for me the one time, but this is my first time logging in after downloading all weekend. Good luck.

[Diablo error 3004 - Forums - Diablo 3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4512732745)