# Why am I getting Error 3003

Tags: diablo-iii

I know this borders on technical support but...

An answer [given here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63631/1762) seems to indicate that Error 3003 represents an error related to not playing in the proper region, although I have the full game and am in the Americas region.

What is the actual technical explanation of this error?  I get Error 3003 about 50% when I try to play and it results in a very long wait for a timeout after attempting a login before I'm told I have a 3003.

Is this just Blizzards way of throttling the number of login attempts made by a single user by closing the connection server side without sending a FIN to the client indicating the connection should be closed?

Comment: Have you tried Blizzard's Diablo technical support forums?

Comment: I haven't.  I like the stack exchange community better :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug that is [affecting many users at this moment](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5152405666). As you can see, the Technical Support is looking after it, and they're working to solve it. For the moment you can try [what the support suggested](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5152405666?page=2#23) and eventually report your experience in that thread on the official forum.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reasons for error 3003 when your internet connection is working is that the Blizzard account servers are down for maintenance.

When getting a 3003 error, look for a message on the Diablo 3 loading screen to see whether the service is down for scheduled maintenance, and when it will return if it is.

For example, at present, Diablo 3 displays the following in the "Breaking News" section for the American region:

> We will be performing scheduled maintenance beginning on Tuesday, May 22, at 1:00 a.m. PDT, and we expect the service to be available again at approximately 9:00 a.m. PDT [12 p.m. Eastern]. During this time the game will be unavailable for play.
>
> Additionally, the Account Management, Blizzard store, Forums, and the rest of our website will be unavailable from 1:00 a.m. PDT until approximately 3:00 a.m. PDT [6 a.m. Eastern].

Apparently, it was the Blizzard store and account servers being down for maintenance that resulted in a 3003 error, as now that the store is back from maintenance, Diablo III is proceeding past the login step, and then displaying a message that the game servers are down for maintenance.

Comment: That can't be it, as it seems to happen during all hours of the day (and not during peak usage) and also when http://us.battle.net/d3/en/status is showing the Americas Game Server status as up.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be something that they have now fixed:

http://us.battle.net/support/en/blog/5658917

> 3003
>
> "Unable to connect to the service or connection was interrupted"
>
> This issue is now resolved.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5152405666) and you'll see that it's not resolved at all.